# Error in XML document (1, 1) while deserializing from web, no error when deserializing local file

Tags: c#, .net, xml

When I download the XML from this [URL](https://publications.elia.be/Publications/Publications/InternetImbalance.v1.svc/GetImbalanceMeasuresByTime) and deserialize from hard disk, there's no error. When I'm deserialize from the URL with Streamreader and Webrequest or XmlDocument.Load or XmlTextReader I got every time the error "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1 "

I've tried already a lot of possible several ways to read the online XML. I also tried to force the encoding to ISO-8859-1 as given in the XML but without result.

```
string path = "http://publications.elia.be/Publications/Publications/InternetImbalance.v1.svc/GetImbalanceMeasuresByTime";
var col = new Model.EliaImbalanceMinutes.AllData();

try
{
    using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(path).GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model.EliaImbalanceMinutes.AllData));
        col = (Model.EliaImbalanceMinutes.AllData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

It gives me this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException HResult=0x80131509 Message=Het XML-document (1, 1) bevat een fout.

Comment: Sounds like the server doesn't respond with the XML when you do it this way. Perhaps it's looking for a browser id, or something, in the request. Have you looked at what's actually there in the response before attempting to parse it as XML?

Comment: It may be that it's lying about the encoding it's using. Try using UTF-8. It may be sending the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and that's where your serializer is hanging.

Comment: That code returns JSON (with an incorrect Content-Type) not XML.  In a Browser XML *is* returned so there is some logic based on request headers being used to determine the response type.

Comment: Add the Accept: application/xml header if you want XML.